# c# winforms how to repeat string array members?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, arrays

First, I need to create a string array from a `DataGridView.SelectedCells.Values`. Then I need to append that string to itself, until a limit of `member.count` is reached. For example, 
if

```
string [] = {"a", "b", "c"};  // Where abc are selectedCells.Values.
```

the new string [] should be:

`{"a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b"}`

- if limit is 8, for example.

How could I solve this, please?

Comment: You are not multiplying, but repeating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the `%` (Modulus) in a for loop.

```
string[] oldArr = new string[3] {"a","b","c"};
string[] newArr = new string[8];
int limit = 8;
for ( int i = 0 ; i < limit ; i++ )
{
    newArr[i] = oldArr[i%oldArr.Length];
}
```

That's it.

Answer (score 3):

Just keep a separate counter for the original array index. Something like:

```
string[] strings = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
string[] final = new string[8];

int index = 0;
for(int i = 0;i < 8;++i)
{
    final[i] = strings[index];
    index = (index + 1) % strings.Length;
}
```

Comment: Assuming that this would be done with a lot more data, wouldn't be better to take a copy of the entire array and then just chop the last one to fit?

Comment: maximum number of members is 64. Maybe not too much. itsme86 - your code works. Could you write about creating initial string from dgvSelecteCells.Values?

Comment: That would be a different question on `SO`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using something like

```
int yourLimit = 8;
int yourIndexer = 0;
string[] strArr = new string[3] { "a", "b", "c" };
List<string> list = new List<string>();
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
{
    if (strArr.Contains(cell.Value.ToString()) && yourIndexer < yourLimit)
        list.Add(cell.Value.ToString());
    yourIndexer++;
}
string[] strNewArr = list.ToArray<string>();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: excellent ! all solutions works. I voted on each. But, which one i should assign as a final solution ?

Answer (score 1):

This version uses `Array.Copy` to do the copying.

```
    {
        int N=10;
        string[] strings=new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
        int L=strings.Length;

        int R = (int) Math.Ceiling(N/(1.0*L));
        string[] result=new string[N];
        for(int index=0; index<R; index++)
        {
            int offset = index*L;
            Array.Copy(strings, 0, result, offset, Math.Min(L, N-offset));
        }
    }
```